# Will spawning in Shadowmere after she dies break my game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I ended up with the marked for death glitch on Shadowmere, giving her negative armor, so I've decided to kill her and spawn her in using console commands. I know I can wait several days for her to respawn, and I hear there's a mod that removes the glitch, but I want to spend as little time as possible on this. I will be making a save beforehand anyway, but I would rather not risk making more progress only to find I've broken my game. I have hearthfire, but not dawnguard or dragonborn.

Note: feel free to edit this wall of text to make it easier to read, I'm terrible at writing.

TL;DR: Will spawning shadowmere with console commands cause difficulty later in the game?

Comment: Just save, do it, if it breaks, go back. Save often so you don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [no known bugs](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere) associated with Shadowmere related to manually respawning him.

Similarly, he's not connected to any quests other than being given to you as a reward for one, which it sounds like you've completed naturally anyhow.

It's possible if you forcibly spawn Shadowmere *before* completing the appropriate quest you might end up with a bug related to the two listed on UESP for already having a horse... but since you're past that point, you should have no trouble.